# Convert structure of array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this array of objects:

```
[{
  "Germany": "text",
  "Brazil": "50.00"
}, {
  "Germany": "1000.00",
  "Brazil": "1100.00"
}, {
  "Germany": "999999999",
  "Brazil": "9999999",
  "France": "12"
}]
```

I want to convert it to the following structure:

```
[{
  "name": "Germany",
  "value": 999999999
}, {
  "name": "Brazil",
  "value": 999999999
}, {
  "name": "France",
  "value": 12
}]
```

Where in the second object we use the higher value for each of the keys in the first object.

Edit: a value could also be text, like `"Germany": "text"` , in that case that value should be ignored. I added that case in the first object above.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: _"...we use the higher value for each of the keys in the first object"_ - Then why there's `France` in the end result? What if the value for `Brazil` in the last object would be `999`? Would the value in the result be `1100.00` then?

Comment: This is a perfect task for any beginner to improve their javascript skills. 
Try splitting the problem up in different steps. 

1. Save all the objects' keys and remove duplicates. 
2. For each key, fetch all values that match that key, and save only the largest number. 
3. Create a new list with the objects in key-value pairs formatted the way you want. 

Tip: you can use the `Object` class to get keys, values and key-value pairs (entries) for each object in the array. 

Tip 2: This isn't really a suitable question for stackoverflow. However, you could search for answers to step 1-3.

Comment: @Andreas Exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.reduce` to iterate over the objects, and `.forEach` to iterate over each object entries:

```js
const data = [
  { "Germany": "100.00", "Brazil": "50.00" }, 
  { "Germany": "1000.00", "Brazil": "1100.00" }, 
  { "Germany": "text", "Brazil": "9999999", "France": "12" }
];

const res = Object.values(data.reduce((acc,item) => {
  Object.entries(item).forEach(([name,value]) => {
    if(!isNaN(value)) {
      const prev = acc[name];
      if(!prev) acc[name] = { name,value } ;
      else if(prev.value < value) prev.value = value;
    }
  });
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: What if I have text instead one of the numbers ? where should I check that it's a number only to compare ?

Comment: @stungbeet can you edit your question and expected result with this scenario?

Comment: @stungbeet I edited the answer to skip records with non-numeric values

Comment: I get `Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'` 
edit: fixed by doing `value as any`

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of `reduce` function to get your expected output. Inside reduce, you can take the `Object.entries` of the current object in order to group by the country name.

```js
const arr = [{
  "Germany": "100.00",
  "Brazil": "50.00"
}, {
  "Germany": "1000.00",
  "Brazil": "1100.00"
}, {
  "Germany": "999999999",
  "Brazil": "9999999",
  "France": "12"
}];

const result = Object.values(arr.reduce((a,e)=>{
    Object.entries(e).forEach(([name, value])=>{
        a[name] ??= {name, value:0};
        a[name].value = a[name].value>value ? a[name].value : value
    });
    return a;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```